# How can I use an array as map value?

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary, containers, stdmap

I'm trying to create a map, where the key is an `int`, and the value is an array as follows:

```
int red[3]   = {1,0,0};
int green[3] = {0,1,0};
int blue[3]  = {0,0,1};

std::map<int, int[3]> colours;

colours.insert(std::pair<int,int[3]>(GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON,red));    // THIS IS LINE 24!
colours.insert(std::pair<int,int[3]>(GLUT_MIDDLE_BUTTON,blue));
colours.insert(std::pair<int,int[3]>(GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON,green));
```

However, when I try to compile this code, I get the following error:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.1-4ubuntu8) 4.4.1

In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_algobase.h:66,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_tree.h:62,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.4/map:60,
                 from ../src/utils.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_pair.h: In constructor ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const _T1&, const _T2&) [with _T1 = int, _T2 = int [3]]’:
../src/utils.cpp:24:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_pair.h:84: error: array used as initializer
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_pair.h: In constructor ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_U1, _U2>&) [with _U1 = int, _U2 = int [3], _T1 = const int, _T2 = int [3]]’:
../src/utils.cpp:24:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_pair.h:101: error: array used as initializer
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/map:61,
                 from ../src/utils.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_map.h: In member function ‘_Tp& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const _Key&) [with _Key = int, _Tp = int [3], _Compare = std::less<int>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, int [3]> >]’:
../src/utils.cpp:30:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_map.h:450: error: conversion from ‘int’ to non-scalar type ‘int [3]’ requested
make: *** [src/utils.o] Error 1
```

I really can't see where the error is. Or even if there's an error.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can't copy arrays by value like that.

Here are several solutions, but I recommend #4 for your needs:

1. Use an `std::vector` instead of an array.
2. Use a map of pointers to arrays of 3 elements:

   ```
   int red[3]   = {1,0,0};
   int green[3] = {0,1,0};
   int blue[3]  = {0,0,1};
   std::map<int,int(*)[3]> colours;
   colours.insert(std::pair<int,int(*)[3]>(GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON,&red));
   colours.insert(std::pair<int,int(*)[3]>(GLUT_MIDDLE_BUTTON,&blue));
   colours.insert(std::pair<int,int(*)[3]>(GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON,&green));
   // Watch out for scope here, you may need to create the arrays on the heap.
   ```
3. Use [boost tuples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html) instead of arrays of 3 elements.
4. Instead of using an array make a new struct that takes 3 elements. Make the `map<int, newstructtype>`. Or wrap your array in a struct as follows:

   ```
   struct Triple
   {
       int color[3];
   };

   // Later in code
   Triple red = {1, 0, 0}, green = {0, 1, 0}, blue = {0, 0, 1};
   std::map<int,Triple> colours;
   colours.insert(std::pair<int,Triple>(GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON,red));
   colours.insert(std::pair<int,Triple>(GLUT_MIDDLE_BUTTON,blue));
   colours.insert(std::pair<int,Triple>(GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON,green));
   ```

Comment: about 3) This is a small project, cant add boost, but will take a look, thanks.

Comment: @Tom: Added a 4) which may be your easiest solution.

Comment: use std::make_pair. See below.

Comment: When inserted in the 2nd way, how can they be accessed? For example, if I need to access the first element of `GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON` I tried doing `colours[0][0] but it's not printing the value I want.

Answer (score 9):

Use [std::tr1::array](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c15257).

```
typedef std::tr1::array<int, 3> Triple;
Triple red   = {1, 0, 0};
Triple green = {0, 1, 0};
Triple blue  = {0, 0, 1};
std::map<int, Triple> colours;
colours.insert(std::make_pair(GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON,   red));
colours.insert(std::make_pair(GLUT_MIDDLE_BUTTON, blue));
colours.insert(std::make_pair(GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON,  green));
```

Or [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) in C++11 and above

```
using  Triple = std::array<int, 3>; 
Triple red   = {1, 0, 0};
Triple green = {0, 1, 0};
Triple blue  = {0, 0, 1};
std::map<int, Triple> colours;
colours.insert(std::make_pair(GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON,   red));
colours.insert(std::make_pair(GLUT_MIDDLE_BUTTON, blue));
colours.insert(std::make_pair(GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON,  green));
```

Comment: also known now as simply `std::array` ;-) making this really the only still-relevant answer left here. weird how it has so few votes...

Answer (score 8):

Arrays are not first class constructs in C++. They are not `Copy Constructible` nor `Assignable` which are requirements for values of `std::map`. You can use `boost::array` or `std::vector`.

Answer (score 7):

Don't map to an int[], instead, map to an int* like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    std::map<int,int*> colors;
    int red[] = {3,7,9};
    colors[52] = red;
    cout << colors[52][1];  //prints 7
    colors[52][1] = 11;
    cout << colors[52][1];  //prints 11
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative is to put the arrays in a wrapping struct:

```
    struct Wrapper { int value[3]; };

    // ...
    Wrapper red = {{1,0,0}};    
    std::map<int,Wrapper> colours;    
    colours.insert(std::pair<int,Wrapper>(1, red));
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays cannot be the stored data in a standard container( `std::pair`)

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to expand on the third item of [Brian R. Bondy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2582533/2675154): Since [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) the class template [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) is available. So you no longer need Boost to work with tuples.

A tuple is a collection of fixed size that can hold multiple elements. Compared to e.g. `std::vector` it has the advantage that it can store heterogeneous types. For example, if you want to store the name of the color together with its RGB values, you can add a fourth element of type `std::string` for the color name to the tuple. But for your specific use case, the code could be written as follows:

```
int main() {
    using col_t = std::tuple<int, int, int>;
    col_t red   = { 1, 0, 0 };
    col_t green = { 0, 1, 0 };
    col_t blue  = { 0, 0, 1 };

    std::map<int, col_t> colours;

    colours.emplace(GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON, red);
    colours.emplace(GLUT_MIDDLE_BUTTON, blue);
    colours.emplace(GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON, green);

    for (auto const &kv : colours)
        std::cout << kv.first << " => { " << std::get<0>(kv.second) << ", "
                                          << std::get<1>(kv.second) << ", "
                                          << std::get<2>(kv.second) << " }" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 0 => { 1, 0, 0 }
> 1 => { 0, 0, 1 }
> 2 => { 0, 1, 0 }

Note: Working with tuples became easier with [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17), espcially if you want to access multiple elements simultaneously.
For example, if you use [structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding), you can print the tuple as follows:

```
for (auto const &[k, v] : colours) {
    auto [r, g, b] = v;
    std::cout << k << " => { " << r << ", " << g << ", " << b << " }" << std::endl;
}
```

[Code on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1916e32d4beb787)

Answer (score 0):

**Approach using structure in C++**

```
int MAX_DATA_PER_INSTR = 8;
//struct to hold the values. remember to write the constructor
struct InstrChar
{
  InstrChar(int in[MAX_DATA_PER_INSTR]) { 
    //c alternative is memcopy
    std::copy(in, in+MAX_DATA_PER_INSTR, data);
  }
  int data[MAX_DATA_PER_INSTR];
};

// create a key value pair 
std::map <int, InstrChar> address_instructions;
std::map <int, InstrChar>::iterator it;

// sample array, 8 elements
int xp[MAX_DATA_PER_INSTR ] = {31,4,3,4,4,3,1,2};
address_instructions.insert(std::pair<int, InstrChar>(PC, xp));
it = address_instructions.find(PC);
InstrChar buf1 = it->second;
//integer pointer to the array, can be dereferenced as *p, *(p+1), ....    //*(p+7)
int *p = buf1.data;

//in case you need to print these values out. They can also be referred to as buf1.data[0], buf1.data[1], buf1.data[2]
printf("%d\n", (*p));
printf("%d\n", *(p+1));
printf("%d\n", *(p+2));
printf("%d\n", *(p+3));
printf("%d\n", *(p+4));
printf("%d\n", *(p+5));
printf("%d\n", *(p+6));
printf("%d\n", *(p+7));
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass an array into the Map function in C++.
this code might help you.
this take the array element as input and insert it into map function with count of occurrence.
**for an array {1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1} Map will be >> element : number of occurrence** 
1  3,
2  2.
3  1,
4  1

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int size;
    cin>>size;
    int arr[size];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    
    map <int,int> mp;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size ;  i++)
        mp[arr[i]]++;
        
        for (auto i = mp.begin(); i != mp.end(); i++) 
        cout << i->first << "      " << i->second << endl; 
        
        return 0;
        //@rsMayank
}
```

Hope it may help you ~ [Mayank Srivastava](https://twitter.com/rs_mayank)