# c++ access elements of the array in a map

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using array as map value: Cant see the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582529/using-array-as-map-value-cant-see-the-error)

Assume I have the following data structure:

```
std::map<size_t, double[2] > trace;
```

how can I access its elements with the operator[]?

Essentially I want to do something like:

```
trace[0][0] = 10.0;
trace[0][1] = 11.0;
```

In compiling these lines of code I get the following error:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_map.h:453:11: error: conversion from ‘int’ to non-scalar type ‘std::map<long unsigned int, double [2]>::mapped_type {aka double [2]}’ requested
```

comments?

Comment: You have an array of double in the map. The map needs a key to store/bind a value to. How did you assign values to the map?

Comment: `std::map<size_t, double[2] >` is that legal? I didn't think you could use arrays in the STL like that.

Comment: this post might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582529/using-array-as-map-value-cant-see-the-error

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: because arrays are neither copyable nor movable.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall If I knew that I wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: consider using `std::map<int, std::array<double, 2>>` instead (if you have that possibility, else `std::map<int, boost::array<double, 2> >`

Comment: @ybunga, sorry, I misinterpreted the OP, for some reason I thought there was a pointer inside ;)

Comment: this is not legal. A c-style array is not copy constructable and therefore can't be used in as a map value.  What compiler are you using? gcc barks about `ISO C++ forbids casting to an array type double[2]`

Comment: @ybungalobill: But I think they are default-constructible, which is all that's required of them here. They'd only need to be copy- or move-constructible if you wanted to use `insert`.

Comment: compiler: g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: strangely enough c++ compiler did not complain about std::map<size_t,double[2]>

Comment: @Mike Seymour is it what exactly happening here? when I reference trace[0], c++ invokes the insert and starts complaining?

Comment: @Mike de Klerk: I assigned the keys with trace[0]. The key in this case is 0, or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: @user8723: Actually I was wrong - you can't use an array, because the language mysteriously forbids you from explicitly value-initialising them, which is required for map's value types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Value types for maps must be default-constructible, using an expression `value_type()`, in order to access them via `[]`. For some mysterious reason, array types are not, as specified in C++11 5.3.2/2 (with my emphasis):

> The expression T(), where T is a simple-type-specifier or typename-specifier for a **non-array** complete object type ... creates a prvalue of the specified type,which is value-initialized

The compiler gives that strange error when trying to value-initialise an array; the following gives the same error:

```
typedef double array[2];
array();
```

I suggest using a class type rather than `double[2]`: `std::array<double,2>`, `std::pair<double,double>`, or a `struct` containing two doubles. Such types are copyable, don't decay into a pointer (losing compile-time knowledge of the size) at the drop of a hat, and are generally easier to deal than a built-in array type.

If you're stuck with an old library that doesn't provide `std::array`, then you could use the very similar [Boost.Array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/array.html), or write your own simple class template to wrap an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap an array:

```
template<typename T, unsigned int n>
struct ArrayWrapper
{
    T v[n];
    T& operator[](unsigned int i) { return v[i]; } // You can also check for out-of-bounds errors
    const T& operator[](unsigned int i) const { return v[i]; } // You can also check for out-of-bounds errors
};
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    typedef std::map<size_t, ArrayWrapper<double,2> > Map;
    Map trace;
    trace[1][0] = 42;
    for(Map::const_iterator it = trace.begin(); it != trace.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << "( " << (*it).first
            << ", " << (*it).second[0]
            << ", " << (*it).second[1]
            << ")\n";
}
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/JpGQFO). Else, if you have C++11, you should use `std::array`; if not, and you have Boost, you can use Boost.Array.

Answer (score 1):

Your code compiles till:

```
std::map<size_t, double[2]> trace;
```

because `double[2]` is a valid type. You can declare a template class object with any valid type. For example:

```
template<typename T>
struct X {
  // T t; // this will complain for sure
  void foo () { T t; } // this won't complain unless invoked !!
};
X<void> x;
```

will compile without any problem.
If you call `x.foo()`, the compiler will complain about it.

Same thing is happening in case of `std::map`. When you invoke functions like `map::insert()`, `map::operator []` where the value-type `double[2]` is actually going to be used, the compiler will start complaining as `double[2]` is not copyable (*exception*: I have seen an old g++3.x version where arrays were assignable and copyable).

You can encapsulate your array into a structure.

```
struct D { double d[2]; };
```

If you want to avoid using raw array then `std::array` is good option as mentioned in comments and other answer.