# Animator in c++ with SDL2

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary, sdl, sdl-2

I try to have a map where the key is an enum, and the value an array of SDL_Rect (which contains) all the coords for the animation.

```
std::map<Animation, SDL_Rect*> animations; 
Animation currAnim;
```

I dont want to define a fixed number of animation like a solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582529/using-array-as-map-value-cant-see-the-error). How can I do ? Because

```
SDL_Rect right[3];
right[0].x = 264;
right[0].y = 0;
right[0].w = 36;
right[0].h = 64;
...
animations.insert(std::pair<Animation, SDL_Rect*>(Animation::MoveRight, right));
```

doesn't work.

I tried this but know I have another problem in my draw, where I must find the element of the vector with an int (frame) :

```
void Player::Draw(SDL_Renderer * renderer, int frame)
{
    std::vector<SDL_Rect>::iterator it = std::find(animator->GetAnimations()[animator->GetCurrAnim()].begin(),
        animator->GetAnimations()[animator->GetCurrAnim()].end(), frame);

    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, lTexture->GetTexture(), &*it, &rect);
}
```

I tried this but there is an error which said

```
'==' There is no operator found which accept type "SDL_Rect"
```

Comment: what does doesn't work mean?  Compile error (include the error), Runtime error (yup, include the error), etc.

Comment: Why do you say an "array of SDL_Rect" when you are storing only a pointer to one of them?  Even so, why use a pointer? `std::map<Animation, SDL_Rect>`  or if truly an array `std::map<Animation, std::vector<SDL_Rect>>`

Comment: @LewisBolender `there is an exception and the program crashes`  Well, you're using pointers where I don't see the need for them.  That alone would be one reason for the program to have issues.  Probably that array goes out of scope, and the map now winds up with garbage data.  If that's the case, use `std::vector<SDL_Rect>` as the key to the map, and not `SDL_Rect *`

Comment: That should say `std::vector<SDL_Rect>` as the data in the map.  By using `SDL_Rect *` as the data, you are tying that map to that array.  If that array goes out of scope your map has invalid values.  In addition, please post more code and explain what line the exception occurs on (instead of saying "it doesn't work").  No one can give you a definitive answer as to what the issue will be unless more code is posted.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the array you're using goes out of scope, thus the pointer you stored in the map is no longer valid.

Since you didn't post all of your code, one suggestion to you is to not store pointers as the data in the map.  Instead, use `std::vector`.

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
typedef std::map<Animation, std::vector<SDL_Rect>> AnimationMap;
//...
AnimationMap animations;
//...
std::vector<SDL_Rect> right(3);
right[0].x = 264;
right[0].y = 0;
right[0].w = 36;
right[0].h = 64;
//...
animations.insert(std::make_pair(Animation::MoveRight, right));
//...
```

If the vector `right` goes out of scope, the map is still ok, as a *copy* of the vector is placed in the data portion of the map.