# insert an array element in an std::map

Tags: c++, stdmap

I don't understand why this code works:

```
std::map<int,char> map2;
map2.insert (std::pair<int,char>(3,'a'));
```

But this doesn't:

```
std::map<int,double[2]> map1;
map1.insert (std::pair<int,double[2]>(100,{0,0}));
```

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you just try to create a `std::pair<int,double[2]>` _without_ inserting it into a map? In other words, is the problem really the insertion, or the construction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you are loooking for is here:
[Using array as map value: can't see the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582529/using-array-as-map-value-cant-see-the-error)

Where the last answer explains it as arrays are not assignable or copy constructible, therefore cannot be mapped to.

As an alternative, you can use pointer arrays or vectors.