# Copying struct into one element of an array

Tags: c++, dictionary, pointers, memcpy

In the code I am working on, I need to do the following:

1. Create a map where each value is buffer of fixed size
2. Use memcpy to populate one element of one value of the map (that is, one element of an array that is itself a value of the map) with some locally defined object

The following code is a small example of the concept:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    struct hdr {
        int cpi_length = 42;
    } ;

    void* this_hdr = new hdr;
    std::map<int, hdr(*)[20]> SP;
    std::cout << sizeof(hdr) << std::endl; // "4"
    std::cout << sizeof(this_hdr) << std::endl; // "4"
    std::cout << sizeof(SP[0][0]); // "80"
    std::memcpy(SP[0][0], this_hdr, sizeof(hdr)); // "Error: access violation"
    std::cout << SP[0][0]->cpi_length;
    return 0;
}
```

This brings me to two problems: 1) how to resolve the runtime error when trying to use memcpy, and 2) once the error is resolved, how do I ensure that this code will do what I described it should do?

As shown with the commands `sizeof`, the instance of the struct being copied in is identical in size to the struct itself, and (apparently) is a lot smaller than the size of the array element it is being copied into. So why the access violation? There should be plenty of room to spare.

I know that it may seem silly why I would use `memcpy` in this instance, why would I use pointers for the buffer instead of a vector, etc. This is just a reproducible example, understand that in the actual code I am restricted to these implementation choices. For now, I am going off of the assumption that I am just making some simple mistake like mixing up the syntax when it comes to referencing/de-referencing pointers.

Comment: Pop quiz: `SP[0]` is a pointer to an array of 20 `hdr`s. Here's a trick question for you: in the shown code, where does `SP[0]` actually point to? This is a trick question because it's not pointing to anywhere. The shown code fails to initialize this pointer, so `SP[0][0]` results in [demons flying out of your nose](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nasal_demon). You need to figure out where this should be pointing to, and adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: I explained at the top of my question what the code is intended to do, so I posted the question asking for how to "adjust the code accordingly" @SamVarshavchik

Comment: Code speaks louder than words.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I verbally described what I want and then wrote a small, reproducible example of what I've attempted so far. What else could I do? Is there an etiquette of stack overflow I'm not familiar with?

Comment: @UpAndAdam That makes a lot of sense, actually. Do you know the syntax to allocate memory for them, or a resource I could get that from? (I know I accepted the other answer but I just want to know my options)

Comment: I'll make it out as an answer you can upvote it and just not accept it thats fine.

Comment: @UpAndAdam: OP does not have an array of ten `hdr*`. OP has one uninitializedd pointer.

Comment: @MooingDuck You are 100% right. I forgot about the rule about that parenthesis. hdr \*[]  is array of pointers vs hdr (\*)[] is pointer to the array.  will also update my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Create a map where each value is buffer of fixed size

That's not what you are doing. Here's the one test you forgot:

```
std::cout << sizeof(SP[0]); // How large is the actual element of the map?
```

Here's a map where each value is a buffer of a fixed size:

```
std::map<int, std::array<hdr, 20>> SP;
```

Comment: When I researched before starting the implementation I was told that arrays cannot be elements of a map https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582529/how-can-i-use-an-array-as-map-value that's why I was trying to use pointers

Comment: @NathanGoedeke `std::array` is a "smart" array. In cases where you don't know the size at compile time, `std::vector` steps in.

Comment: When trying your implementation then trying to access SP[0][0] (the first element of the array indexed at 0 in the map) gives the syntax error: no operator "[]" matches these operands: std::array<hdr, 20U>[int]. Is there different syntax to access the array?

Comment: Did you include `<array>`? Also remember that `SP[0][0]` isn't a pointer anymore.

Comment: @user4581301 I'm not sure if I can use smart arrays in the system I am using, but I guess technically speaking your answer does work

Comment: @NathanGoedeke https://godbolt.org/z/TWG8c45Pf

Comment: @NathanGoedeke If you can't use `std::array`, fake it out. All `std::array` is is a normal array inside a `class` with a couple support functions like operator `[]`. You can knock one of your own out in a few minutes. As soon as you put the array in a structure, you can pass around the structure by value and it'll carry the array with it. With the extra support functions you'll hardly be able to tell the difference between it and a normal array. Side note: The answer is n.m.'s not mine.

Comment: @NathanGoedeke `SP[0][0]` is NOT the first element of the array. It is the array itself (or, it would be, if you actually allocated an array anywhere). `SP` is a map, `SP[0]` is a pointer to an array, `SP[0][0]` is an array, and `SP[0][0][0]` is the first item of the array.

Comment: @MooingDuck I used the syntax of the question I linked in the above comment, which said: `Use a map of pointers to arrays of 3 elements: std::map<int,int(*)[3]> colours;` What syntax would create the data structure I actually want?

Comment: `std::map<int, std::array<int,3>>`

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes that's the answer already given by n. m. I was asking how would the implementation look if it was using pointers instead of std::array

Comment: @NathanGoedeke UpAndAdam looks to have that covered. But take his advice and don't do it.

Comment: If you wanted a pointer, next best is `std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<std::array<int,3>>>`

Comment: @NathanGoedeke If you use pointers, they need to point to something, and you need to manage allocation of that something. Not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

The other option if you really want to go with dynamic memory is quite simple.  Just remember you also have to clean up after yourself, I would still strongly suggest using a `std::array` for the syntactical clarity and convenience. Because it is so much cleaner and dirty feeling I have also included that variant as well.

I think both of the non-std::array ways of allocating are pretty bad, I don't like using `malloc` in `C++` and I also feel like having to reinterpret_cast the result of `new` is bad / not something I generally recall having to do.  The `std::array` is much much cleaner, though a smart pointer would be even better.

And it always feels a little silly to me to use non smart pointers in the map because then you have to either keep a seperate container for all the memory ownership to make sure you delete it all (which is fairly common at least in placement new memory pool cases) or you have to wrap the class with your in inserter/deleter so that you make sure you destroy (destructor and free memory) any object you remove from the map. (again unless you delegate memory ownership to a secondary structure)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <cstring> // for memcpy
#include <array>

int main()
{
    struct hdr {
        int cpi_length = 42;
    };

    hdr* this_hdr = new hdr; // notice not using void* here
    std::map<int, hdr(*)[20]> SP; // ok each int points to an array of 20 hdr pointers.
    // for contrast
    std::map<int, *std::array<hdr, 20>> SP2;

    // ok lets fill in one of them:
    // the C styleish way (note this technically would also be a reinterpret cast to go from void * to hdr(*)[20] )
    SP[0] = (hdr (*)[20])malloc(sizeof(hdr)*20); //allocate the memory for the array of 20 hdr's
    // OR the C++ish way without std::array
    // Note I really don't like having to reinterpret_cast this
    // SP[0] = reinterpret_cast<hdr (*)[20]>(new hdr[20]);
    // and for contrast     
    SP2[0] = new std::array<hdr, 20>;

    std::memcpy(&SP[0][0], static_cast<void *>(this_hdr), sizeof(hdr)); // now copy it
    std::memcpy(&SP2[0][0], static_cast<void *>(this_hdr), sizeof(hdr)); // now copy it

    std::cout << SP[0][0]->cpi_length;
    std::cout << SP2[0][0]->cpi_length;

    //ok all done
    free(SP[0]);
    // OR if you used NEW ABOVE
    // delete [] SP[0];
    delete SP2[0];
    delete this_hdr;
    //destructor for SP will do the rest...
    return 0;
}
```